# How to divide Time in float form (hh.mm) by an integer in ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to divide Time in float form (hh.mm) by an integer.
For example 1.30 by 2 must give 00.45.
Is there any simple way to do this?

Comment: Is that your input? `1.30` as an hour and a half?

Comment: @SebastianPalma yes

Comment: @Emmanu : Is there a particular reason why you use a Float to represent such a value?

Comment: Do you mean `0.45` or `"00.45"`? If the former, please drop the leading zero; if the latter please add quotes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using a float to express `h.mm` is a bit unusual. You would typically use strings for formatting.

However, I'd start by extracting hours and minutes from the float value. To do so, I would convert the float to a string using [`format`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Kernel.html#method-i-format):

```
time = 1.3
time_str = format('%.2f', time)
#=> "1.30"
```

Then I would [`split`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/String.html#method-i-split) the string at `.` to get the hour part and minutes part and call [`to_i`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/String.html#method-i-to_i) to convert them to actual integers: (I'm using [`map`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Array.html#method-i-map) here, you could also call `h = h.to_i` / `m = m.to_i` afterwards)

```
h, m = time_str.split('.').map(&:to_i)
h #=> 1
m #=> 30
```

Now that we have the numbers `1` and `30` as integers, we can easily calculate the total duration in minutes:

```
duration = h * 60 + m
#=> 90
```

I would then divide the duration by 2 (or whatever value):

```
duration /= 2
#=> 45
```

and convert it back to hours and minutes using [`divmod`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Numeric.html#method-i-divmod): (it returns both values at once)

```
h, m = duration.divmod(60)
h #=> 0
m #=> 45
```

We can format these as a string:

```
format('%02d.%02d', h, m)
#=> "00.45"
```

or convert it back to a float:

```
time = h + m.fdiv(100)
#=> 0.45
```

Which can be formatted like this:

```
format('%05.2f', time)
#=> "00.45"
```

Comment: Agreed, 1.30 is an odd way to represent hours & minutes (at least in US?). 1.5 or 1:30 makes more sense. This answer is great example of how to parse & convert it however

Comment: @JayDorsey indeed. And if you wanted to change the dot to a colon, you couldn’t use float anyway. It’s the wrong representation in the first place. 1.30 isn’t a decimal value.

Answer (score 1):

```
time    = 1.3
divisor = 2

hr, min = (time.fdiv(divisor)).divmod(1)
  #=> [0, 0.65]
min = (60 * min).round
  #=> 39 
"%02d.%02d" % [hr, min]
  #=> "00.39"
```

Another example.

```
time    = 1005
divisor =    5

hr, min = (time.fdiv(divisor)).divmod(1)
  #=> [201, 0.0] 
"%02d.%02d" % [hr, (60 * min).round]
  #=> "201.00"
```

See [Integer#fdiv](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Integer.html#method-i-fdiv), [Float#fdiv](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Integer.html#method-i-round), [Integer#divmod](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Integer.html#method-i-divmod) and [Integer#round](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Integer.html#method-i-round). `divmod` is an extremely useful method that, for reasons I don't understand, seems to be under-used.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can split into an array an then:

```
n = 2
[1, 30].then { |h, m| [h / n, (m + h % n * 60) / n]}
#=> [0, 45]
```

For splitting:

```
num = 1.3
('%.2f' % num).split('.').map(&:to_i) #=> [1, 30]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following :

```
num = 1.3

splitted_values = ('%.2f' % num).split('.').map(&:to_i) => [1, 30]

((splitted_values[0] * 60) / 2) + (splitted_values[1] / 2 ) => 45
```

Comment: it works..but it gives time in minutes...for..3.00 it gives 90...thats right. but it is in minutes